# PgHero gem error "No connection pool for 'PgHero::Connection::Database337600' found."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, blazer, pghero

I'm using RubyOnRails 6.1 with [multiDB setup](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html): primary and follower.
`CustomDatabaseResolver` is configured to distribute load between databases.

```
class CustomDatabaseResolver < ActiveRecord::Middleware::DatabaseSelector::Resolver
  def read_from_primary?
    super || rand(2).zero?
  end
end
```

I think this configuration creates a problem for [pgHero](https://github.com/ankane/pghero) gem because its dashboard is randomly crashing with the error:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
No connection pool for 'PgHero::Connection::Database337600' found.
```

I cannot find a way this can be fixed.
I have tried to force pgHero controller to use primary, but no luck.

```
# config/initializers/pghero.rb
Rails.application.reloader.to_prepare do
  PgHero::HomeController.send :include, WriterDbRoleExecutor
end

# app/controllers/concerns/writer_db_role_executor.rb
module WriterDbRoleExecutor
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    around_action { |_controller, action| ApplicationRecord.force_writer_db_role(&action) }
  end
end
```

Btw, same approach did helped with another gem - [blazer](https://github.com/ankane/blazer)

```
Rails.application.reloader.to_prepare do
  Blazer::BaseController.send :include, WriterDbRoleExecutor
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually got fixed by prepending around action:

```
prepend_around_action { |_controller, action| ApplicationRecord.force_writer_db_role(&action) }
```

There are some controller callbacks in `PgHero::HomeController` that make db connections, and we should ensure our callback got fired first.